# spacy Matcher: get original keys

Tags: spacy

Once I got a match with Spacy's `Matcher`, I want to get the key of the match. According to [this guide](https://spacy.io/api/matcher), one can specify a key once initializing:

```
matcher_ex = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher_ex.add("mickey_key", None, [{"ORTH": "Mickey"}])
matcher_ex.add("minnie_key", None, [{"ORTH": "Minnie"}])
```

Next I run matching:

```
doc = nlp("Ub Iwerks designed Mickey's body out of circles in order to make the character simple to animate")
matcher_ex(doc)
# [(7888036183581346977, 3, 4)]
```

That's where it gets strange. It returns some other integer key, and I cannot figure out how to match that integer key `7888036183581346977` to `mickey_key`. This is what `help(matcher_ex)` says:

```
Call docstring:
Find all token sequences matching the supplied pattern.

doclike (Doc or Span): The document to match over.
RETURNS (list): A list of `(key, start, end)` tuples,
    describing the matches. A match tuple describes a span
    `doc[start:end]`. The `label_id` and `key` are both integers.
```

The object has no property `label_id`, but it is anyway seems not what I am looking for.

Seems like the `Matcher` must keep them both somewhere:

```
matcher_ex.has_key('mickey_key') # True
matcher_ex.has_key(7888036183581346977) # True
```

but docs say nothing how to match them. I tried code introspection, but it's all in C.

Any idea how to match `7888036183581346977` to `mickey_key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nlp.vocab_strings` to retrieve rule ids.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher_ex = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

matcher_ex.add("mickey_key", None, [{"ORTH": "Mickey"}])
matcher_ex.add("minnie_key", None, [{"ORTH": "Minnie"}])

doc = nlp("Ub Iwerks designed Mickey's body out of circles in order to make the character simple to animate")
matches = matcher_ex(doc)  # [(7888036183581346977, 3, 4)]
print(matches)
# [(7888036183581346977, 3, 4)]

rule_ids = dict()
for match in matches:
    rule_ids[match[0]] = nlp.vocab.strings[match[0]]
print(rule_ids)
# {7888036183581346977: 'mickey_key'}
```